# How can I add some additional 5 volt power

Tags: power

I have an Arduino which is being powered by a 9v, 2 amp power supply.  I have about 20 relays which are powered by 5 volts each.  I do not want to over work the voltage regulator on the board, so I would like to add another (possible 2) 5 volt regulator that I bought on amazon.  I am planning to:

1. Connect the regulators VIN to the Arduino's vcc (9 volt)
2. Connect the regulator's GND to the Arduino's GND.
3. Connect the regulator's VOUT to the Relay's VCC

At this point, can I also connect the regulator's VOUT to the Arduino's 5volt out?

Also, is it possible (or advisable) to add second voltage regulator to the first in a parallel configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> At this point, can I also connect the regulator's VOUT to the Arduino's 5volt out?

Absolutely. But don't daisy-chain the regulator to each supply input in turn, connect each one separately directly from the regulator.

> Also, is it possible (or advisable) to add second voltage regulator to the first in a parallel configuration?

It is not advisable. Small manufacturing differences between regulators can result in them outputting slightly different voltages, which will lead to destruction of hardware.